# How to remove a physical volume from a volume group in a running system

Tags: lvm

I have the following problem:

I have two Volume Groups, `VG00` and `VG01`. I wanted to extend `VG01` by 600GB, but accidentally extended `VG00`.

What I did was:

- add new Disk to virtual Machine (vmware)
- create a partition with `cfdisk`
- create the physical volume:

  ```
  pvcreate /dev/sdg1
  ```
- extend the volume group:

  ```
  vgextend /dev/mapper/VG00 /dev/sdg1
  ```
- extend the logical volume:

  ```
  lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/VG00-root
  ```
- resize the filesystem:

  ```
  resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/VG00-root
  ```

Then I noticed my mistake.

Is there now a way to revert that and add the physical volume to the other volume group/logical volume without having to umount it? Its a running Server and we are talking about the root LV.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) there was no need for partioning (you could have use /dev/dsg ), 2) you used all space in /dev/sdg, you will have to unmount and shrink VG00-root. be sure to test shrinking FS on a test VM **before**

Comment: You have to do all these steps in reverse. Many filesystems can grow, but not shrink... without unmounting. Another option might be to merge these VGs and/or just use the space directly, this depends on the purpose of your storage layout...

Comment: If this is a VM backed by image files, i.e. it's a thin volume / sparse file / ... and those 600GB don't actually take up any real storage (while not in use) you could also just add another 600GB volume for now and clean this up properly later.